# Jacoco test reports showing 0 coverage. Execution data does not match

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, travis-ci, jacoco

I have a [small app](https://github.com/Prokky/GameShare) which I started to learn unit and instrumental tests. I successfully wrote some and integrated Travis-CI, now I want to generate Jacoco reports for Codecov.io, but everytime I run ./gradlew jacocoTestReport it generates 0% coverage one, same as when Travis-CI does.

In my log I see `Execution data for class ** does not match`

I tried cleaning before, but it doesnt help. 
Still got 0% coverage 
https://codecov.io/gh/Prokky/GameShare

https://travis-ci.org/Prokky/GameShare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrolambda was the problem. The library modified the classes, so Jacoco throwed exceptions and didn't work. Disabling Retrolambda (or Jack, if you are using it) will solve the problem.

Comment: So you removed it? You can still get code coverage with Retrolambda, see my example here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gif-example/blob/master/gradle/codeQuality.gradle#L49.